# Get hostname from Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hostname

I am trying to get the hostname of the machine which a rails application is running on from the controller.

What would be the best way to do this taking into account it should work on both windows and linux?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's always:

```
require 'socket'
...
Socket.gethostname
```

I've got no Windows box handy with which to test this, but the docs make no mention of it being *nix specific.

Note: The require statement is not necessary for Rails 4, and probably other Rails versions as well.  It is required if you are doing plain Ruby without Rails.

Comment: It doesn't look like the first line is needed any more on Rails 4.

Comment: @ohaleck Thank you for pointing that out.  I've amended the answer.

Answer (score 99):

All you have to do is look at the request object in your controller:

```
request.host_with_port
```

or if you don't want the port, just

```
request.host
```

Comment: this is helpful for if you are trying to parse URL's and such, but I think this particular question pertains to the actual name of that machine or OS.

Comment: this wont help you if you want to get the internal name of the host

Answer (score 9):

Use backticks and the command `hostname`

```
current_host = `hostname`
```

This sends the command to the shell, and returns the hostname. Works on at least: Debian Linux, Windows, Solaris.

Comment: If you're going to do this I'd recommend caching the value via an initializer, and not doing a fork() for each request.

Comment: Works on Mac OS as well.

Comment: Shelling out when you don't need to in general is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the full domain path from protocol to port, try:

```
full_domain_path = request.env['rack.url_scheme'] + '://' + request.host_with_port
```