# How to get host name in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am facing an issue with the host name in rails 3.

I need to access host in `config/initializers/file.rb but without socket gem and any gem.

host like app url

```
www.app.com
```

Could you please let me know that how it would be possible for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154914/how-to-get-host-name-in-rails-3

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, I have to get without any gem. thanks

Comment: which gems are you talking about? What I showed you is a copy of your question where you have bunch of options

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208835/get-hostname-from-rails-controller

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, I am trying to get it in config/initializers/file.rb so when I try to get it in this file, it return "rails"'.

Comment: "socket" is not a gem.  It is a library that comes with Ruby.  Why can't you use it?

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't get a hold of a request object in an initializer, you'll need to use [`socket` from the standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html). Socket is not gem, so no gem installation is necessary!

Et viola:

```
require 'socket'
Socket.gethostname
```

This assumes though that host name of your device matches the address you seek (run the command `hostname` in the terminal to see what I mean). If that's not the case, you won't be able to determine the host name until a request is made, since any number of addresses can point to the same application. It might be wiser to set this through configuration variables.

If you really want something dynamic, the closest you can get is by performing the initializer within a controller. Here's an example that will dynamically set `action_mailer.default_url_options` based on the first request made to the server.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_mailer_host

  private

  def set_mailer_host
    if !ProMetrics::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
      ProMetrics::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: request.host, port: request.port }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Socket.gethostname return "rails"  in config/initializers/file.rb so it is not working for me. thanks

Comment: That's the actual hostname of the computer (i.e. same result as typing `hostname` in bash). You're not going to be able to determine a host name until you make a request since any number of addresses can point to the same host. You should consider moving this configuration step into a controller.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps just a simple system call:

```
`hostname`.chomp
```